# Convex curve $\iff$ convex set

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The definitions I use are the following:

> **Definition by supporting lines** (Convex Curve): A **convex curve** is a curve in the Euclidean plane ($\mathbb{R}^2$) which lies completely on one side of each and every one of its tangent lines ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_curve)).

and

> **Definition** (Convex Set): A **convex set** $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a set of points such that, given any two points $v, w \in A$, the line-segment $[v,w]$ lies entirely within that set [(Wikibooks)](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Convexity/What_is_a_convex_set%3F).

I want to prove that given a bounded set $D \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ with a smooth boundary, that 
$$
\text{$D$ is convex}\iff \text{$\partial D$ is a convex curve}
$$

where $\partial D = \overline{D} \backslash D^{\circ}$ is the boundary of $D$.

I am aware of the fact that there are two other posts highlighting ([link 1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1727310/convex-curve-as-boundary-of-a-convex-set), [link 2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2105151/proof-that-a-set-c-is-convex-iff-its-intersection-with-any-line-is-convex?rq=1)) the same problem (maybe with some differences in definitions), but the way the proofs/questions were formulated were pretty vague.

For the longest time I haven't been able to figure out a formal proof, while it is tauntingly intuitive. Do you guys have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I might need some extra conditions that I have overlooked.

Comment: If you want a really formal proof, I think that first definition needs to be tightened up quite a bit. What does it mean for a tangent line to *lie completely on one side of a curve*? What is a *side* of a curve anyways? I think this gets into tricky stuff. Tricky like how distinguishing between the *outside* and *inside* of a closed curve is tricky. See the [Jordan curve theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_curve_theorem).

Comment: Is it not formal enough to say the following:
Take an arbitrary $x \in \partial D$, then there exists a tangent line $L$ going through $x$.
The tangent line $L$ divides the plane into two closed half-planes (*.*), and if $D$ lies completely in one of the two closed half-planes, then the curve $\partial D$ is convex.

If I had to point out where the definition is not formal, then I would point to (*.*).

Comment: I would solve that problem by parametrising the line $L$ by $y = at + b$ for some constants $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$. Subsequently, I would define the two half-planes by $\mathbb{H}_1 = \{(t,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \leq at + b\}$ and $\mathbb{H}_2 = \{(t,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid y \geq at + b\}$.

Comment: "there are two other posts highlighting the same problem" It would be nice if you could share the links to them for reference.

Comment: Anyway, a proof by contradiction seems like the most natural approach here. Suppose $\partial D$ is a convex curve but $D$ is not a convex set, derive a contradiction, repeat vice versa.

Comment: @Rahul I added the links. Oh and by the way, I agree with that it is most natural deriving it via contradiction. Unfortunately I still get stuck.